# Consuming restful symfony2 with angularJs Client

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony

I want create an application using symfony2 in server side and angularJs in client side. 
I create a restful api with friendsofsymfony but I still doesn't know how can I consume the Json data generated by the api with angular. I found in some tutorials that I can split the two part of the project and so I should now create a simple HTML project with AngularJS. But I still have no idea how can I do this!

Can someone help me please with some instructions or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so difficult. Two files backend and frontend.

**Backend**: you should install symfony, setup it, create controller.
In controller setup route with request method(for youe wish get, post, put delete).

**Frontend**: (if you know little bit angularjs) create main mod, create controller and by $http send request to your symfomy's controller and get your data.

P.s. And don't forget read about [serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). **It's so much important!!!**

More detail you can read [here](https://medium.com/@llaine/operate-with-harmony-symfony2-angularjs-283b641d3b05#.l8scx1hjl).

Comment: Thank you @Bakhtier Gaybulloev for your unswer. I will try to follow your advice.But what about twig and symfony routing?

Comment: More detail you can read about twing and routing combination http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html and here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html. Symfony has a perfect docs at official website. But I don't recommend you use twig in big project. Nice project should be divided to frontend and backend part.

Comment: So if I want to divide my project to frontend and backend part I will not need twig because the angular syntaxe are very similar

Comment: Yep. Plus when you will write your frontend you will use something like bower. And it will be more easy.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help I will try to create my frontend app now